# Layout 3 columns without faux-columns

Tags: html, css, layout

i need to do a 3 columns layout without faux columns on sides.
I cant use faux columns because i need to manage this columns with javascript.

Anyone can suggest me what i can do? an example of the work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jVnJX/3/
The right column must be attached to the footer.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: No faux columns? You mean real, actual columns? Ehm, how about using a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery:

```
var left_height = $('#column-sx').height();
$('#column-dx').css('height', left_height);
```

​See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVnJX/4/)